# VBA shrinking Font Size

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a VBA code to save a pdf copy of a worksheet, but when this VBA runs it causes the font within some (not all) cells to become very very small in the pdf.

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I've attached a picture of the pdf file to show what's happening.

Here is the end of the VBA that I'm running.

---

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=FilePath & DocName & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

[image]

Comment: unable to replicate. i'm certain there's nothing in this snippet of code that is causing this behavior. perhaps there are some formatting/settings/etc on the workbook or worksheet itself (though I wouldn't know where to begin looking for this) that you can tinker with.  Can you reproduce the same problem on other worksheets and in other workbooks?  Can you reproduce the problem on another computer?

Answer (score 1):

I identified the issue as a combobox that continued to prompt to select an option from the dropdown. I resolved this by replacing Change() with GotFocus()

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()

    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "JobList"

    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
```

before your code, then

```
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

after